# MassTransit error at cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context)

Tags: masstransit

See my code below the error above happens at `cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);`

The error is

> "No service for type
> 'MassTransit.Saga.ISagaRepository`1[SlideX.Core.StateMachines.OrderState]'
> has been registered.'
> The docker compose is below

---

```
> version: '3.4'
> 
> services:
>   hostedservice:
>     image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}hostedservice
>     build:
>       context: .
>       dockerfile: HostedService/Dockerfile
>   rabbitmq:
>     image: masstransit/rabbitmq:latest
>     ports:
>      - "5672:5672"
>      - "15672:15672"
>      - "15692:15692"
```

---

```
{
   services.AddMassTransit(x =>
   {
      x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();

      x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

      // By default, sagas are in-memory, but should be changed to a durable
      // saga repository.
      
      x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();

      x.AddSagaStateMachine<OrderStateMachine, OrderState>(typeof(OrderStateMachineDefinition));                        

      x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
      {
        if (IsRunningInContainer)
        cfg.Host("rabbitmq");

        cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();

         cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
         });
       });
       services.AddLogging();
       services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);
});
```

Comment: I am creating a docker container for the host service and RabbitMQ

Answer (score 0):

The use of:

```cs
x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider()
```

is only called when using the non-generic `AddSaga` and `AddSagaStateMachine` methods. So you'd need to change to:

```cs
x.AddSagaStateMachine(typeof(OrderStateMachine), typeof(OrderStateMachineDefinition));
```

The providers were intended for use with bulk registration, since the extension methods for specifying the saga repository aren't available in the bulk methods.